# Generate sequential number in SQL - not by using Identity

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a task where my query will produce a fixed width column. One of the fields in the fixed width column needs to be a sequentially generated number.

Below is my query:

```
select
_row_ord = 40,
_cid = t.client_num,
_segment = 'ABC',
_value = 
concat(
'ABC*',
'XX**', --Hierarchical ID number-this field should be sequentially generated
'20*',
'1*','~'
    )
from #temp1 t
```

My output:

[image]

Is there a way to declare @num as a parameter that generates number sequentially?

PS: The fields inside the CONCAT function is all hardcoded. Only the 'XX' i.e., the sequential number has to be dynamically generated

Any help?!

Comment: Hint: `row_number()`

Comment: I would ask why do you want this? Smashing sequential values inside a string is often a sign that you are not normalizing your data correctly. It is almost an indication of violating 1NF by stuffing multiple values into a single tuple. And how are you going to sort this correctly? And how are you going to handle when you run out of numbers because it looks like you want length of 2? What happens when you hit 100?

Comment: Do you have any maximum limit for this sequentially generated number part ?Is that below 100?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? `SELECT @@VERSION;`

Comment: I am not having any limit for the sequential number generated.

Comment: I am using SQL server 2014

Comment: Based on your sample data, you could use the last 2 characters of `_cid`.

Comment: Since you aren't limiting the length of the number I would argue even stronger that this is a bad idea. You can't use that value for ordering. 9 will sort after 14746. I think if you "solve" this you are going to just create another problem for yourself. This should be a separate column, not part of a single column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a [`SEQUENCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql) object, then call the [`NEXT VALUE FOR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql) the `SEQUENCE` in your query.

Something along these lines:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.ExportValues
    START WITH 1  
    INCREMENT BY 1 ;  
GO
```

And then:

```
select
_row_ord = 40,
_cid = t.client_num,
_segment = 'ABC',
_value = 
concat(
'ABC*',
RIGHT(CONCAT('000000000000000', NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.ExportValues),15)
'**', 
'20*',
'1*','~'
    )
from #temp1 t
```

You'd have to tweak how many zeros there are for the padding and how many digits to trim it to for your requirements. If duplicate values are ok, you could have the `SEQUENCE` reset periodically. See the documentation for more on that. It's just another line in the `CREATE` statement.

Comment: Thanks Eric. This is helpful

Comment: Glad it was useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` -- made a little more complicated because you are zero-padding it:

```
select _row_ord = 40, _cid = t.client_num, _segment = 'ABC',
       _value = concat('ABC*',
                       right('00' + convert(varchar(255), row_number() over (order by ?)), 2),
'XX**', --Hierarchical ID number-this field should be sequentially generated
                       '20*',
                       '1*','~'
                       )
from #temp1 t;
```

Note that the `?` is for the column that specifies the ordering.  If you don't care about the ordering of the numbers, use `(select null)` in place of the `?`.

Comment: row_number can change between runs of the query as rows are added/removed from the table.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff your answer only work below 100 of the sequential number

Comment: @AnushaSubashini . . . It wasn't me.  The OP only has two digits for the number.